# Material-UI Dropdown Menu Navigation

Tags: navigation, material-ui

I am using Material-ui v1 beta and I want to have a series of dropdown Menus across the top for my navigation. This is primarily a web App - - I see the AppBar component with a menu item but not a dropdown and I see the Simple Menu that is a dropdown that would work but it says to not use it for primary navigation.

I am wondering why not?

What is the best practice for navigation?

Any suggestions for a top of the screen dropdown navigation system - preferably tied to react-router ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [drawer component](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/drawers/) instead of [menu component](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/menus/).
`Drawer component` is very flexible and works nicely if you need to support responsive design. There is [a responsive drawer](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/drawers/#responsive-drawer) already available for this purpose. Also, [material-ui website](https://material-ui-next.com) uses drawers as their leftmost menu so you can see how it works by changing the size of the browser window.

Here is an example how I used drawer component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { MenuItem } from 'material-ui/Menu';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import Toolbar from 'material-ui/Toolbar';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';
import List from 'material-ui/List';
import ListItemText from 'material-ui/List/ListItemText';
import Hidden from 'material-ui/Hidden';
import LinkButton from '../LinkButton/LinkButton'
import CustomIconButton from '../CustomAppBar/CustomIconButton/CustomIconButton';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';
import {Routes, ReportTypes} from '../../constants';

import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';

const drawerWidth = 250;


const styles = theme => ({
    navIconHide: {
        display: 'block',
        [theme.breakpoints.up('xl')]: {
            display: 'none'
        }
    },

    drawerPaper: {
        width: drawerWidth,
        left: 0,
        [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
            width: drawerWidth
        }
    }
});

const menuItemLinks = [
    {
        text: "All reports",
        path: "/"
    }, {
        text: ReportTypes.STATIC_ANALYSIS,
        path: Routes.STATIC_ANALYSIS_DETAILS
    }, {
        text: ReportTypes.SLOC,
        path: Routes.SLOC_DETAILS
    }, {
        text: ReportTypes.UNIT_TEST_RESULTS,
        path: Routes.UNIT_TEST_DETAILS
    }, {
        text: ReportTypes.UNIT_TEST_COVERAGE,
        path: Routes.UNIT_TEST_COVERAGE
    }
]


class AppBarMenu extends React.Component {

    state = {
        open: false
    }

    handleRequestClose = event => {
        this.setState({ open: false });
    }

    handleDrawerToggle = () => {
        this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
    }

    getMenuItem(menuPath, text, key) {
        const {path} = this.props

        return <MenuItem
            onClick={this.handleRequestClose}
            selected={menuPath === path}
            key={key}
            to={menuPath}
            component={LinkButton}>
            <ListItemText primary={text}> </ListItemText>
            {menuPath === path ? <FontAwesome name="angle-right"/> : ''}
        </MenuItem>
    }

    getMenuItems() {
        return menuItemLinks.map((menuItem, key) => this.getMenuItem(menuItem.path, menuItem.text, key))
    }

    render() {
        return this.getDrawer()
    }

    getDrawer() {

        const { classes } = this.props;

        const drawer = (
            <div>
                <Toolbar className={classes.drawerHeader} >
                    <Typography variant="title" color="inherit">Reports</Typography>
                </Toolbar>
                <List>{this.getMenuItems()}</List>
            </div>
        )

        return (
            <div>
                <CustomIconButton
                    iconName='bars'
                    aria-label="open drawer"
                    onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle}
                    className={classes.navIconHide}>
                    <Hidden xlUp>
                        <Drawer
                            variant="temporary"
                            anchor='left'
                            open={this.state.open}
                            classes={{
                                paper: classes.drawerPaper
                            }}
                            onClose={this.handleDrawerToggle}
                            ModalProps={{
                                keepMounted: true
                            }}>
                            {drawer}
                        </Drawer>
                    </Hidden>
                </CustomIconButton>
                <Hidden lgDown>
                    <Drawer
                        variant="permanent"
                        open
                        classes={{
                            paper: classes.drawerPaper
                        }}>
                        {drawer}
                    </Drawer>
                </Hidden>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default withStyles(styles)(AppBarMenu);
```